# Component cannot be used as a JSX component. Property '$props' is missing in type X but required in type 'ElementClass'

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

I'm getting this typescript error from basically every component in VSCode, both custom and library components. This is an expo build for react native. This command yields the same results:
`yarn tsc --project tsconfig.json`

here's an example in VSCode
[image]

and an example of the full error message:

```
'KeyboardAvoidingView' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'KeyboardAvoidingView' is not a valid JSX element.
    Property '$props' is missing in type 'TimerMixin & KeyboardAvoidingViewComponent' but required in type 'ElementClass'.ts(2786)
```

This is my .tsconfig:

```
{
  "extends": "../../node_modules/expo/tsconfig.base",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

and this is expo's that it extends:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Expo",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  },

  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem
I just added this to package.json then run yarn

```
"resolutions": {
   "@types/react": "17.0.2",
   "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2"
},
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71833347/18377369)