# 'PersistGate' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, persist

my project was working well until yesterday, but from this morning I have this issue:

```
'PersistGate' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'PersistGate' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
```

and I used the other guys solutions like add resolutions into the packages.json but it has just changed the error to another files :|.

My app.tsx:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { store, persistor } from "src/Redux";

import { GlobalStyles } from "@components";
import { theme } from "@utils";
import { ModuleMain } from "@modules";
import "@translations/i18n";

function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <GlobalStyles />
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                    <ModuleMain />
                </PersistGate>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native 'PersistGate' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its instance type 'PersistGate' is not a valid JSX element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71826046/react-native-persistgate-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component-its-instance-type)

Comment: Not actually.

Not fixed with it

Comment: Have you tried ? `import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react'`